# FullCalendar global width

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I tried to find a solution to resize my calendar on the webpage. But it is still blocked.

Here is what I have :

[image]

I used this trick to have the calendar height to be good :

```
function get_calendar_height() {
            return $(window).height() - 30;
        }

$(window).resize(function(){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', get_calendar_height());
            });
```

And then option :

```
height: get_calendar_height
```

The problem is that I would like this calendar width to be 80%. I wrote in css :

```
#calendar{
    width: 80%;
}
```

But it is not working..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you, either share your code with us or create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we're able to take a closer look at it?

Comment: To set the width please use `#calendar{
  width:80% !important;
}` . You may use the `!important` To override  the inline style which is width:100%.

Comment: Sorry. I did wrong in my js code. Indeed, I wrote a div <style> with max-width set as 1500 px in my html. That's why it was not working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outer div for calendar and set its with:

```
<div class="outer" style="width:80%;">
   <div id="calendar">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried. The caldendar is moved to the left (just a bit). And that's all. The div is not sized as 80%..

Comment: Please Create a fiddle or share a link of this page